# R: Generate sub data frame with groupings of date ranges

Tags: r

I have a data frame containg two columns, an identifier and a date. The code below creates a sample data frame.

```
x <- c(rep(c("a","b"), each=10), rep(c("c", "d"), each=5))
y <- c(seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-01-05"), by = 1), 
    as.Date("2014-03-12"), 
    as.Date("2014-03-15"),
    seq(as.Date("2014-05-11"), as.Date("2014-05-13"), by = 1),
    seq(as.Date("2014-06-11"), as.Date("2014-06-14"), by = 1),
    seq(as.Date("2014-06-01"), as.Date("2014-06-20"), by = 2),
    seq(as.Date("2014-07-31"), as.Date("2014-08-05"), by = 1))  

df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
```

The following is the output of `df`.

> x      y
>   1  a 2014-01-01
>   2  a 2014-01-02
>   3  a 2014-01-03
>   4  a 2014-01-04
>   5  a 2014-01-05
>   6  a 2014-03-12
>   7  a 2014-03-15
>   8  a 2014-05-11
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   23 c 2014-06-17
>   24 c 2014-06-19
>   25 c 2014-07-31
>   26 d 2014-08-01
>   27 d 2014-08-02
>   28 d 2014-08-03
>   29 d 2014-08-04
>   30 d 2014-08-05

I would like to create another data frame that summarises the date ranges; i.e. for each x an entry will be created for each contiguous set of dates. The output I would like (based on the data in df) is the following:

> x start.rng      end.rng       days.rng
>   a 2014-01-01      2014-01-05      5
>   a 2014-03-12      2014-03-12      1
>   a 2014-03-15      2014-03-15      1
>   a 2014-05-11      2014-05-13      3
>   b 2014-06-11      2014-06-14      4
>   b 2014-06-01      2014-06-01      1
>   b 2014-06-03      2014-06-03      1
>   b 2014-06-05      2014-06-05      1
>   b 2014-06-07      2014-06-07      1
>   b 2014-06-09      2014-06-09      1
>   b 2014-06-11      2014-06-11      1
>   c 2014-06-13      2014-06-13      1
>   c 2014-06-15      2014-06-15      1
>   c 2014-06-17      2014-06-17      1
>   c 2014-06-19      2014-06-19      1
>   c 2014-07-31      2014-07-31      1
>   d 2014-08-01      2014-08-05      5

I am unable to figure out how to go about this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 res <- do.call(rbind, 
     lapply(split(df, df$x), function(.df)
         do.call(rbind, lapply(split(.df, 
cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(.df$y) != 1))), function(.x)
      data.frame(x = .x[1, 1], start.rng = .x[1, 
2], end.rng = .x[nrow(.x), 2], days.rng = nrow(.x))))))

row.names(res) <- 1:nrow(res)
head(res)
#  x  start.rng    end.rng days.rng
#1 a 2014-01-01 2014-01-05        5
#2 a 2014-03-12 2014-03-12        1
#3 a 2014-03-15 2014-03-15        1
#4 a 2014-05-11 2014-05-13        3
#5 b 2014-06-11 2014-06-14        4
#6 b 2014-06-01 2014-06-01        1
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 DT1 <- setDT(df)[,indx:= cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(y)!=1)),
          by=x][,list(start.rng=y[1], end.rng=y[.N], days.rng=.N),
          by=list(x, indx)][, indx:=NULL] 

  head(DT1)
 #   x  start.rng    end.rng days.rng
 #1: a 2014-01-01 2014-01-05        5
 #2: a 2014-03-12 2014-03-12        1
 #3: a 2014-03-15 2014-03-15        1
 #4: a 2014-05-11 2014-05-13        3
 #5: b 2014-06-11 2014-06-14        4
 #6: b 2014-06-01 2014-06-01        1
```

#### Explanation

I will try to explain by splitting the codes in `data.table`

- Check for the difference between consecutive row values in `y` for each `x` group

  ```
     setDT(df)[, #converts `df` from `data.frame` to `data.table`
      indx:=  #create an index 
    c(0, diff(y)), by=x] #calculates the difference between consecutive `y` elements
       #for each `x` group.  Here `diff` returns one element less than the length of each `x` group.  So, I appended `0` to it.  It can be any value other than `1` so that in the next step, I can use it to create a `grouping` index
  ```
- Create a grouping index of `indx` from the above step

  ```
   df[, indx1:=cumsum(indx!=1), by=x] # you can check the result of this step to understand the process.
  ```
- Using the `indx1` as a new grouping variable in addition to `x`, we check for the `first` and `last` value of `y`

  ```
      df1 <-  df[, 
         list(start.rng=y[1], #first y value 
          end.rng=y[.N], #last y value .N signifies the length of each group
          day.rng=.N),  #group length i.e. .N
           by=list(x, indx1)] #grouped by x and indx1
  ```
- If you don't want the column `indx1`,

  ```
     df1[, indx1:=NULL]
  ```

Comment: Thank you - works. Still trying to figure out how you did it :-)

Comment: @chribonn I updated the solution with some explanation.  Hope it helps